# CSS3 nth-child() repeat range every 5 elements

Tags: css, css-selectors

It's possible to select a range of element each 5 elements? What i expect:

```
<ul>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li> //this
   <li>Test</li> //this
   <li>Test</li> //this
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li> //this
   <li>Test</li> //this
   <li>Test</li> //this
   <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

From 2 to 4, from 7 to 9, etc.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use a class?

Comment: The HTML was only for example. I will use a class when i write my real code :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since your range has the form [5 *n* - 3, 5 *n* - 2, 5 *n* - 1] (where *n* ≥ 1), use the following code:

```css
li:nth-child(5n - 3), li:nth-child(5n - 2), li:nth-child(5n - 1) {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
   <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Then i need a code for all the elements? If i must select 7 elements i must create 7 selectors?

Comment: @Alex Ferreli: Pretty much, since :nth-child() is limited to An+B expressions.

Comment: Ok, i got it. Thank you :)